# Resizing the height of tabelview according to the content size so that it only scroll when it doesn't fit into the view?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I already checked all the answer related to this. My code only works if I disable or enabling scrolling from storyboard not from my code.

It always shows the content size height and tableview height as same. I am not using Autolayout.

```
[tableView reloadData];
tableView.frame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height;
```

Comment: Add some code. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self adjustHeightOfTableview];
}
```

write `adjustHeightOfTableview` this method as

```
- (void)adjustHeightOfTableview
{
    CGFloat height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat maxHeight = self.tableView.superview.frame.size.height - self.tableView.frame.origin.y;

    // if the height of the content is greater than the maxHeight of
    // total space on the screen, limit the height to the size of the
    // superview.

    if (height > maxHeight)
        height = maxHeight;

    // now set the frame accordingly

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
        frame.size.height = height;
        self.tableView.frame = frame;

        // if you have other controls that should be resized/moved to accommodate
        // the resized tableview, do that here, too
    }];
}
```

Hope it helps.